# Error setting up Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, amazon-ec2

[Following this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), I'm attempting to set up Ruby on Rails using Amazon's EC2. For my instance I've selected "Basic 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2010.11.1 Beta". I have ruby, sqlite, and rubygems installed. I'm on step 3.3 of the linked guide which is to run the following command

> bundle install

The result is the following. I'm sure I've just missed something, but I'm at a loss. Any suggestions?

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems    /installer.rb:529:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
```

**EDIT**: Following the suggestion below to install ruby-devel, I now get this error in addition to the original one.

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `build_extensions': 
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

But when I try to run

> yum install sqlite-devel

I'm told:

```
Package sqlite-devel-3.6.20-1.6.amzn1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: My guess is you are missing a compiler package

Comment: did you fix this issue? I am having the same exact issue when trying to configure this on AWS

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the libsqlite3-dev before

`$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

and retry to install the gem after

`$ gem install sqlite3-ruby`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the packages above, mas sure you have gcc and make installed.

They are needed to build the gems you are installing in addition to the development libraries.

Comment: I was missing gcc and I would've never checked it without reading this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
yum install ruby-devel
yum install sqlite-devel
```

NOT sqlite3-devel

Answer (score 0):

Venturing a guess here, but you might be missing a few development packages. Try running:

`yum install ruby-devel sqlite3-devel`

Comment: Getting closer. Installed ruby-devel. Now I get additional errors. Please see op.

Comment: You should do what it says! `yum install sqlite3-devel`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't quite quick enough with my edit. I did indeed do as it suggested.

Comment: `sqlite` and `sqlite3` are different packages. Try `yum install sqlite3-devel` again.

Comment: There is no sqlite3-devel package. Though the description for sqlite-devel is 
`Development tools for the sqlite3 embeddable SQL database engine` 
So I believe it's v.3